# How to block texts from certain number

Tags: sms-blocking

I get spam texts from a certain number (five digit number). Does anyone know how to block texts from specified numbers? I am on a nexus 5 android 4.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get spam messages all the time as well. Normally if you go to your phone carrier and ask them if they can block a certain number for you they most likely will be able to. I have Verizon so when I go to My Verizon online there is a tab you can click on to block numbers, so if your carrier has a website then that is also an option to explore if you can't go into your local carrier store.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 3rd-party SMS app called [GO SMS Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) to "block" SMS from certain numbers. What it actually does is hide (or move) the SMS from that "blocked" number to a different area (SMS Blocker module), so it doesn't show up in the message list. Further SMS from that number will also be hidden, but you can still take a look at them (at SMS Blocker) if you want to.

As with what Austin Harris said, check with your telco if you have a service for reporting spammers. In my country (and telco), we can screenshot the SMS and tweet/report it to them.